# Why componentWillMount is called after rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with React and I am trying to understand the lifecycle. I am doing a `componentWillMount` method in order to get the `props` I need before the render occurs. I need to know how to update the state when the view loads.

All I am trying to do is a `GET` request in order to get a list of dealers for a Casino Game. Basically, I am missing 1 or 2 steps which are for render the dealers's list in the DOM

I will show what I am doing with my code and after that I will explain what I want

Actions part

**getDealerActions.js**

```
class GetDealersActions {

  constructor () {
    this.generateActions('dealerDataSuccess', 'dealerDataFail');
  }

  getDealers (data) {
    const that = this;
    that.dispatch();
    axios.get('someroute/get-dealers/get-dealers')
      .then(function success (response) {
        that.actions.dealerDataSuccess({...response.data});
      })
  }
};
```

then we move to the stores

**getDealersStore.js**

```
class GetDealersStore {

  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      dealerData : null,
    };
  }

  @bind(GetDealersActions.dealerDataSuccess)
  dealerDataSuccess (data) {
    this.setState({
      dealerData : data,
    });
   console.log(this.state.dealerData);
  }
}
```

in this case that `console.log(this.state.dealerData);` returns something like this which is exactly what I need

```
Object {dealersData: Array[3]}
```

the problems comes in the component part, honestly because I don't know how to handle the data here

```
@connectToStores
export default class Dealers extends Component {

  static contextTypes = {
    router : React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  static getStores () {
    return [ GetDealersStore ];
  }

  static getPropsFromStores () {
    return GetDealersStore.getState();
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    console.log('@@@', this.props);
    GetDealersActions.getDealers();
  }

  render () {
    console.log('>>>', this.props);
    let content;
    if (this.state.dealerData) {
      content = this.state.dealerData.map((item) => {
        return <div key={item.CardId}>{item}</div>;
      });
    } else {
      content = <div>Loading . . .</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>{content}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

all I get here `<div>{content}</div>` is `Loading . . .` because `this.state` is coming like this `Object {}`

A weird situation I am getting here, is that this view is rendering twice, the 1st time is rendering, and the `console.log('>>>', this.props);` returns this `>>> Object {params: Object, query: Object}` and the second time it renders, fires this `>>> Object {params: Object, query: Object, dealerData: Object}` which is what I need.

So, why `componentWillMount` is waiting the render method in order to get fired ?

Answer (score 7):

It's not weird at all. `componentWillMount` will fire before render, and in the first-pass you are invoking an action to get the dealers `GetDealersActions.getDealers();` which is basically an async command. Since it is async, the component will render once before it gets data, and then again after the store publishes a `changed` event, which will re-trigger rendering.

Here is an approximation of the sequence of actions happening in your example:

1. `componentWillMount` invokes `getDealers` command (which is async)
2. initial `render` with default component state
3. Async operation completed in action creator and store is set with `dealer` data
4. store publishes a `changed` event, which re-triggers rendering
5. second `render` invoked with the `dealer` data in component state.

The problem is that React will run it's lifecycle methods in a certain sequence, not caring about you invoking some async method. So basically you don't have a way to stop `rendering` just because you invoked a command to get the `dealers`. That is a limitation of `react` (or a feature), which surfaces when combined with async programming and you should accept it as is.

If you accept the fact that React will render twice, you can utilize that in your favor, so on first render you could just show a `loading` indicator (e.g. a spinning wheel) and when the data loads you just display it in the second `render`.

However, if you are not convinced and still want to avoid double-rendering in the initial load, you could do prefetching of the data before you mount the application component, which would ensure that initial data is loaded in the store before the first `render`, which would mean that you wouldn't have to invoke `getDealers` in `componentWillMount` since the data would already be in the store on the first `render`.

As a reminder, double-rendering is not a significant performance problem, like it would be in Angular.js or Ember.js, since React is very efficient at DOM manipulation, but it could produce some UX issues if not handled properly.

Comment: are able to provide me a code example of how I should do that ? I am a just a junior dev and I am working in this project by myself.

Comment: You can find an example in the Facebook samples. They prefetch all messages before rendering the app component in `app.js` https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-chat/js/app.js

Comment: I really get what you said in your answer. But this not enough for me to understand. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Async programming is hard. If you understand how async calls work in JavaScript you will understand my answer. The async callback is scheduled/executed after the initial `render`, which is basically causing the behavior above.

Comment: the how do I update the state in the constructor ? `this.state {dealerData: dealerData}` ?

Comment: yes, but I mean, if I do that and console.log(this.state.dealerData) I will get that dealerData is no defined or something similar. so, how do I get the real data ?

Comment: Yes, true. I have updated my answer to give you one more possible solution. Basically you can just utilize the initial render to show a loading indicator, which is a pretty nice option.

Comment: can you provide a bit of code in your answer? please

Comment: I need to avoid double rendering in order to approach componentWillMount, because I don't want this.props empty in the beginning.